# Reversible compression of a gas - faulty reasoning?

Tags: thermodynamics, entropy, reversibility, gas

I am trying to figure out where my reasoning falls apart in this thought experiment:

To determine if a process "A" is reversible (or at the very least internally reversible), I try to picture a reversible process "B" that involves only heat transfer and links the same two endpoints that bound process "A".

In this particular case, "A" is the reversible adiabatic compression of a fixed mass of any one ideal gas confined in a frictionless piston-cylinder arrangement. Given that a reversible process by definition does not lead to entropy generation, the gas undergoes isentropic compression and receives an amount of energy equal to the PV work done by the piston upon the gas. State 1, then, can be characterized by entropy s1 = s, temperature T1 and volume V1. State 2 can be correspondingly be defined by s2 = s and temperature T2 != T1 (different), and volume V2.

"B" is as follows: first, heat is removed reversibly from the system while the volume is kept constant until the pressure and temperature are only infinitesimally above absolute zero. At this point, the piston is allowed to move, changing the volume from V1 to V2. Once again the volume is kept fixed by some means and heat input is effected reversibly. Since the internal energy of an ideal gas is dependent only on its temperature, an amount of heat different from that which was removed at the beginning of the process must flow inward so as to attain temperature T2, which is different from T1. It follows that the amount of entropy transfer must also be different, which would entail different entropy values for the initial and final states, which is unverifiable in process "A". However, the volume V2 and temperature T2 are the same as those which lie at the end of process "A", which is the same as saying that both states are identical.

My question is: where have I made a mistake? Is it because the ideal gas hypothesis falls apart over this range of different temperatures/pressures? Or is it the assumption of constant specfic heat? If so, how does the underlying mathematics "know" this and reflect accordingly?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: I did not read the rest after "Given that a reversible process by definition does not lead to entropy generation, the gas undergoes isentropic compression ..." This is incorrect. An adiabatic (no heat exchanged) and reversible process is isentropic, but this is not the only way to be reversible. Any reversible process is such that the total entropy is unchanged, adiabatic or diathermal; here total entropy means the sum of the entropies of the system under consideration and that of  its environment, and not just of the system.

Comment: Your reasoning is faulty in the first two statements of your presentation. First of all, it is not true that a “reversible process does not lead to entropy generation”.  For example, a reversible isothermal expansion generates entropy. It’s a reversible cycle that does not generate entropy. Next, if process A is a reversible adiabatic (isentropic) compression, then T2 can’t equal T1. T2 has to be higher than T1. I don’t think anyone can address the rest of your question until your correct the above. I hope this is of help.

Comment: @BobD  This is not correct.  There are two ways that entropy can change within a system:  (a) by irreversible generation of entropy within the system and (b) by entropy exchange with the surroundings across the boundaries of the system.  In a reversible process, only the 2nd mechanism is operative.

Comment: I did state T2 is different from T1 ("State 2 can be correspondingly be defined by s2 = s and temperature T2 != T1...").
@hyportnex That is correct. I left out that the compression is effected **without heat exchange**. In that case, if it's reversible, then it has to be isentropic. I'll amend it.

Comment: @BobD If a process involves no irreversibilites, internal and external, then no entropy is generated. If that weren't the case, a reversible cycle as you described it would involve a process that would "generate" negative entropy.

Comment: @ChesterMiller.

Comment: @ChesterMiller. When I said a reversible cycle does not generate entropy I was referring to a complete reversible thermodynamic cycle, such as the Carnot Cycle, which returns both the system and surroundings to their original states.  When I said a reversible isothermal expansion process generates entropy, I was referring to system entropy. For example in the Carnot Cycle, that process increases the entropy of the system by Qin/TH. The reversible isothermal compression in the Carnot Cycle decreases system entropy by the same amount Qout/TL.

Comment: @jvf. Don't you mean "if a CYCLE involves no irreversibilites, internal and external, then no entropy is generated" ? Would you not agree that a reversible isothermal expansion PROCESS  increases system entropy? Isn't that the case for the reversible isothermal expansion portion of the Carnot Cycle? The reversible isothermal compression portion of the Carnot Cycle then decreases the system entropy by the same amount.

Comment: @BobD In the reversible examples you gave, there is no entropy generated within the system; there is entropy *exchanged* between the system and its surroundings.  Only in irreversible processes is there entropy generated within the system.  See Moran et al, Fundamentals of Engineering Thermodynamics, Chapter 6.  Even for an irreversible cycle, the entropy of the system does not change because the entropy generated within the system is transferred to the surroundings.

Comment: @ChesterMiller. YES of course. I never said the TOTAL entropy increases. In the Carnot Cycle there is an entropy increase to the system in the reversible isothermal expansion that equals the entropy decrease of the surroundings, so the TOTAL entropy change (system + surroundings) is zero. Likewise the entropy decrease in the system during the reversible isothermal compression equals the increase in entropy of the surroundings so the total entropy change (system+surroundings) is zero.

Comment: @BobD My only issue with what you said was the use of "entropy *generated*" to describe a reversible process.  In a reversible process, there is no entropy generated, only entropy exchanged between system and surroundings.

Comment: @ChesterMiller. OK. I meant "generated" in the sense that there is an increase in entropy of the system, not total entropy increase. I didn't realize the term "generated" meant total entropy change. I sure won't use it again except in that context. Live and learn. Thanks.

Comment: @jvf. See my latest comment to Chester about the use of the term "generated".  I think that puts us all on the same page. Thanks.

Comment: @BobD  It doesn't mean total entropy change.  It means entropy generated within the system during an irreversible process (due to irreversibility).  The total entropy change also includes exchange of entropy with the surroundings across the interface with the surroundings.

Comment: @ChesterMiller. OK so the term "generated"  only means entropy generated within a system during an irreversible process. Thanks.

Comment: @BobD Yep, I believe our disagreement was entirely due to differing uses of the word "generate". It shouldn't be used synonymously with "increase". I'm just not entirely sure I'm in agreement with Chester's definition of it. If at the completion of a process total entropy has changed by some non-zero amount, the total entropy generated would be, as I see it, equal to such difference. If he's referring to the entropy generation term as written in the second law for a system, then sure, it's the entropy generated within it during an irreversible process.

Comment: @ChesterMiller.

Comment: @jvf. I'm sorry  my misuse of the term "generated" in connection with entropy caused all this confusion. I have obtained a dictionary of thermodynamic terms to prevent that  from happening again. Bottom line, terminology aside, I think you, I and Chester have a common understanding of the fundamental principles. So before the site turns us off, I suggest we can leave it at that. Thank you and Chester for my education.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I didn't read about process B, but your results for process A are definitely incorrect.  For the isothermal reversible compression you described, the entropy of the system definitely decreases.  When you compress the gas, the amount of heat you remove from the system must equal to work you do in compressing the gas, if the temperature is to remain constant.  So the entropy change is equal to the heat removed from the system (or the work done on the system) divided by the constant absolute temperature.  Even though entropy is not generated within the system during this reversible process, entropy is nonetheless exchanged with the surroundings (by the removal of heat).

**ANALYSIS OF PROCESS B**

The change in entropy of the initial cooling step in process B is $$\Delta S=nC_v\ln{(T_{L1}/T_1)}$$where $T_{L1}$ is the low temperature at the end of the step.  When the gas is adiabatically compressed during the second step, we have to control the motion of the piston such that process is reversible and the change in entropy is zero.  This will require the temperature to rise from $T_{L1}$ to $T_{L2}$ such that $$nC_V\ln{(T_{L2}/T_{L1})}+nR\ln{(V_2/V_1)}=0$$Finally, when we reheat the gas back up to $T_2$, the change in entropy will be $$\Delta S=nC_v\ln{(T_{2}/T_{L2})}$$When we add these three changes in entropy together for process B, we obtain for the overall change:$$\Delta S =nC_V\ln{(T_{2}/T_{1})}+nR\ln{(V_2/V_1)}=0$$This is the same as the entropy change for process A.

Comment: It isn't a reversible isothermal compression, it's **isentropic**: " State 2 can be correspondingly be defined by s2 = s and temperature T2 != T1, and volume V2." T2 is different from T1

Comment: You mean != is supposed to mean $\neq$?  I didn't get that.  Maybe you should learn how to use LaTex?  If that's the case, then your assessment of process A is indeed correct.

Comment: I'll be back to analyze process B in a little while.

Comment: Yes, != indicates difference. Maybe I should get around to learning LaTex... I'm less than a beginner when it comes to using it. Could you give consideration to the remainder of my question?

Comment: See my analysis of process B.

Comment: I apologize, I hadn't seen your last comment. I suppose that even when TL1 and TL2 are both only infinitesimally large, this logic still applies. At first, I just assumed that, since PV work done on a gas over a finite volume difference and with infinitesimal pressure wouldn't produce finite work, the temperature would effectively remain the same: **just** above zero. The infinitesimal work would however cause an infinitesimal increment in temperature, which should explain the equality.

Comment: If the temperature were allowed to not only approach but to be equal to absolute zero, the definition of entropy would become mathematically unsound, and I guess one wouldn't be allowed to just group the integrals with a coincident boundary, which would be equivalent to grouping the ln terms (saying for example that ln(2/1) = ln(2/0 * 0/1)).

Comment: Since I never encountered temperatures exactly at absolute zero during my 35 year career as a chemical engineer in industry, I can’t really speculate intelligently on this.

Comment: Nice answer. I guess this engineering and entertaining unrealistic scenarios don't usually intersect. Maybe a more mathematics-oriented view on this would be of more benefit? Here, have an up-vote.